# How can I open old Gnome Keyring files?

Tags: keyrings, gnome-keyring

I know the password to my old Gnome Keyring files, but how can I open them from my new installation? [1] The keyring import option doesn't recognise the `.keyring` and `.keystore.abc` files in the old `.local/share/keyrings` folder.

Is there another way to open them?

[1] I don't have my old installation anymore, only the home folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any `.keyring` files in the `~/.local/share/keyrings/` folder, should be read by the keyring automatically. However, applications may not necessarily try to read any data from them. You should be able to see them in the list inside the *Passwords and Keys* (*seahorse*) application. You should be able to unlock them inside there, to browse and view the secrets.

Comment: so I could rename my old keyring file to old.keyring, move all the old files into the new keyring folder, and Seahorse will pick up old.keyring and its .keystore.abc files?

Comment: It should just work, yes. It worked for me, when I moved in an old keyring from an old home directory.

Comment: Currently, in 2022, Ubuntu 20.04, this no longer works